# Error Uninitialized string offset: 2 al tratar de guardar datos de array en base de datos

Tags: php, laravel, array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hola amigos, tengo este error al tratar de guardar los datos en mi base de datos, creo que el problema es como itero los array al guardarlos, agradezco su ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$pensum = new Pensum ();
$pensum  ->carrera = $request ->carrera;
$pensum  ->regimen = $request ->regimen;
$pensum  ->vigencia = $request ->vigencia;
$pensum ->numerosemestres = $request ->numerosemestres;
$pensum -> save();



for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->numerodesemestre) ; $i++) {


$semestre= new Semestre ();
$semestre->semestre = $request->numerodesemestre[$i];
$pensum ->semestre()->save($semestre);



if (isset($request->asignatura1[$i])) {

 $asignatura = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura1[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura1[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}


if (isset($request->asignatura2[$i])) {

 $asignatura = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura2[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura2[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}

if (isset($request->asignatura3[$i])) {

 $asignatura= Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura3[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura3[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}


if (isset($request->asignatura4[$i])) {

 $asignatura= Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura4[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura4[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}





if (isset($request->asignatura5[$i])) {

 $asignatura = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura5[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura5[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}

if (isset($request->asignatura6[$i])) {

$asignatura= Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura6[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura6[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}


if (isset($request->asignatura7[$i])) {

 $asignatura = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura7[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura7[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}


if (isset($request->asignatura8[$i])) {

 $asignatura = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura8[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura8[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}

if (isset($request->asignatura9[$i])) {

$asignatura = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura9[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura9[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}


if (isset($request->asignatura10[$i])) {

 $asignatura = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura10[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura10[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}


if (isset($request->asignatura11[$i])) {

$asignatura = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura11[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura11[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}



}



if ($pensum->save() AND $semestre->save() AND $asignatura->save()  ) {


return view ('nuevo-pensum' )
->with('mensaje', 'Guardado exitosamente');


}


else {
return view ('nuevo-pensum' )
->with('errormensaje', 'Hubo un error al guardar el registro');



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas mal Amigo
if (isset($request->asignatura11[$i])) {

$asignatura = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura11[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura11[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);

}

Ya que si quieres hacer un ntercambio diagonal De Opciones Del dsgh No podras Ya que el codigo Interbiene Operaciones Binarias Y al ponerla Al  En un bixer Las soluciones Cambian Asi Que tienes que Cambiar El codigo Utilizando El porft Arreglalo Si te interesa Yo ya estoy rescribiendo Todo

Comment: me interesa amigo.

Comment: au no encuentro la solucion a esto